# Y axis limits change displayed plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

With this code

```
f9 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_smooth(data = pred.dat, mapping = aes(x = month, y = fit)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(3, 6, 9), 
                     labels = c("March", "June", "September")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2)) +
  xlab("Month") + 
  ylab("Predicted number of RHDV releases"); x11(); f9
```

I produce this figure
[image: Figure 1]

You will notice that in the above code I have tried to set the y axis breaks using `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2))`. However, this has not worked.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225050/changing-y-axis-breaks-in-ggplot2) that I need to include a call to `limits =` as follows `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2), limits = c(0, 2))`.

If I re-run my figure code with the new call to y axis limits it completely changes my figure. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. I am wanting to produce the same figure as the top figure in this post but with a y axis that ranges from 0-2.

```
f9 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_smooth(data = pred.dat, mapping = aes(x = month, y = fit)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(3, 6, 9), 
                     labels = c("March", "June", "September")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2), limits = c(0, 2)) +
  xlab("Month") + 
  ylab("Predicted number of RHDV releases"); x11(); f9
```

The above code produces the below figure which is completely different to the first figure. Why and how might I fix this?

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685952/12957340

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. So simple!

Comment: No problem at all - thanks for including all the relevant details in your question